# R I need help understanding my professor's R code to compute exact confidence interval

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-methods, confidence-interval

I am having difficulty understanding particular lines in my professor's example for calculating the exact confidence interval (note: this is not utilizing the normality assumption)

```
# R code for Exact CI

n<- 19; k<- 3
alp<- 0.05; mar<- 1.0e-4

B <- 10^5; x <- matrix(0, B, 1)

# Calculate the left endpoint of the exact CI
for (i in 0:B) {
    p <- i/B
    x[i] <- pbinom((k-1), n, p)
}
x[(abs(x - (1-alp/2)) <= mar)] 
pi_L <- mean(which(abs(x - (1-alp/2)) <= mar)/B)

# Calculate the right endpoint of the exact CI
for (i in 0:B) {
    p <- i/B
    x[i] <- pbinom(k, n, p)
}
x[(abs(x - alp/2) <= mar)] 
pi_U <- mean(which(abs(x - alp/2) <= mar)/B)

# The obtained exact CI
pi_L; pi_U
```

The parts I do not understand:

```
x[(abs(x - (1-alp/2)) <= mar)] 
pi_L <- mean(which(abs(x - (1-alp/2)) <= mar)/B)
#####
x[(abs(x - alp/2) <= mar)] 
pi_U <- mean(which(abs(x - alp/2) <= mar)/B)
```

I do not know what role "<= mar" or "which(abs(x - alp/2)" plays into this.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you having problems with what the symbols mean (i.e. `<= ` mans smaller or equal than) or the math behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure you've asked a very specific answerable question here. If you are taking a class and have questions about your professor's code, then you should probably ask your professor. Otherwise there are help pages for all the functions that are being used that you could check. Try running the parts by themselves to see what they do.

Comment: Some of both.  I would say I need more help with the code than the math, but my experience with numerical methods is a bit lacking too.

Comment: Getting help with statistical theory is not on-topic for SO.